# Python 3: Can't import class from newly imported submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-packaging

```
  2 from core import base_model
```

----> 3 from base_model import BaseModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_model'

I'm a bit confused as to why I cannot import a class called BaseModel in the base_module submodule of the core module, given that I was able to successfully import the submodule base_module.

Comment: Just do `from core.base_model import BaseModel`.  The import scheme looks at file paths, not at imported names.

Comment: because *there is no module named `base_model`*. The name of the module is `core.base_model`

Comment: But note, that import statement is just a roundabout way of doing `BaseModel = base_model.BaseModel`